# Show that $I-A$ is invertible iff $a_{k,k} \neq 1$ for all $k$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inverse

Let $p \in [1,\infty)$. Let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} |a_{k,l}|^q \right)^\frac pq < \infty$ for $qp=q+p$. And let $a_{k,l}=0$ for $l>k$.
Define
$$A: \mathscr l^p \to \mathscr l^p; \quad A(x_k)_k=\left( \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_{k,l} x_l\right)_k.$$

> Show that $I-A$ is invertible iff $a_{k,k} \neq 1$ for all $k$.

My idea was to show $\lVert A \rVert < 1$ and use the Neumann series.

Comment: My first thought is that $A$ is an infinite upper triangular matrix, so I'd try to imitate the finite-dimensional proof.

Comment: Isn't it lower triangle?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I meant.  I don't understand how I came to type "upper".  Senior moment, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the sequences $e_k $ defined by $(e_k)_j = \delta_{jk}$. What is the action of $I - A$ on them?

Comment: I'm curious where you are going with this. Even in finite dimension, the action of a triangular matrix on the canonical basis is not pretty.